# Why does Hunting make sense?

Tags: black-desert-online

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Hunting life skill. I've done the basic questline for Hunting and it's all fine and well. What I don't understand is; how is Hunting different than say... just killing the mob and slaughtering it?

I hear people hunt for instance Feather Wolves for meat. Well I can also kill them normally for meat. Killing them with a slow musket would be a lot slower and less efficient.

What am I missing here? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between hunting and killing regularly is speed. Enemies that are designated for hunting take significantly less damage from normal attacks than normal enemies. For this reason, an appropriately-strong matchlock will kill them much faster than normal combat as matchlocks do not have reduced damage against hunting targets.

You can generally tell these enemies by their icon on the minimap: normal enemies have a dot as their icon, but enemies designated for hunting will have a head as an icon.

[image: icon for a hunt-able enemy]

Comment: Ah. Finding designated mobs was the missing link. Makes more sense now, thank you :-)